# Is there a difference between "Read-Host -Prompt" and "Read-Host"?

Tags: powershell

I am learning PowerShell and want to know the difference between

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Text"
```

and

```
Read-Host "Text"
```

Is it the same thing or is there a difference I am not seeing?

[image: Example Code that does the same thing when executed]

Answer (score 3):

It's the same thing. What's happening here is that parameters can (sometimes, usually) be used named or positionally.

So in this case you are still supplying a value for the `-Prompt` parameter, you just aren't specifically referring to it by name.

A fancy way to see that this is happening is with the `Trace-Command` cmdlet:

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { Read-Host "Hello" } -PSHost
```

Output:

> ```
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Read-Host]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Read-Host]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND REMAININGARGUMENTS cmd line args to param: [Prompt]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to parameter
> [Prompt]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Object]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]] to param
> [Prompt] SUCCESSFUL
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Read-Host]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
> Hello: hi
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
> hi
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The help text for `Read-Host` shows the syntax diagram:

```
PS> help Read-Host

Read-Host [[-Prompt] <Object>] [-AsSecureString]
          [-InformationAction {SilentlyContinue | Stop | Continue | Inquire | Ignore | Suspend}]
          [-InformationVariable <System.Stringr>] [<CommonParameters>]

...
```

The complete description of how these syntax diagrams should be read is available from the built-in help (see `help about_Command_Syntax`.) The pertinent part is:

> ```
> -- Brackets ([ ]) indicate optional items. A parameter and its value can be
>    optional, or the name of a required parameter can be optional.
> ```

So in the case of the `-Prompt` argument, both the parameter *and* its value are optional.